# Spectrum of Free Strings

Tags: string-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spectrum of Free Strings](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26992/spectrum-of-free-strings)

As far as I understand, both in bosonic and superstring theory one considers initially a free string propagating through D-dimensional Minkowskispace. Regardless what quantization one uses at the end one arrives at a spectrum, where the excitations are classified among other things by the representation of the *Poincaré* group (or maybe a cover) they are in, this allows to speak of their mass, but seems to make the construction very dependent on the background. Do massless modes remain massless in an other background, for example? And how does one define the mass of excitations in this case?

Moreover D'Hoker states in his lectures in Quantum Fields and Strings, that he is not aware of a proof that in a general background a Hilbertspace can be constructed. Is there still none?

Comment: Cross-posted to http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/q/1062/189